# not use an angular2-fullcalendar

Tags: angular, npm

I referred to https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fullcalendar.
But, It will not be displayed properly.
Only the header part of calendar is displayed.
Where is the mistake?

```
npm install ap-angular2-fullcalendar --save
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CalendarComponent} from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CalendarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

style.css

```
@import "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";
```

app.component.html

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {CalendarComponent} from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';


  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;

  changeCalendarView(view) {
    this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView', view);
  }

  calendarOptions:Object = {
    height: 'parent',
    fixedWeekCount : false,
    defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2016-09-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2016-09-07',
        end: '2016-09-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2016-09-11',
        end: '2016-09-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2016-09-28'
      }
    ]
  };

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbS7O.png)

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: I saw the browser console.There was no error there.

Comment: okay found the issue..remove the height:parent from your options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow using the height:parent config in your options setting the height of the calendar body to 0 so you need to comment that out to see the calendar.

Comment: Because Japanese information is not enough, it was very helpful.
In the future, I made information on Japanese so that other Japanese do not suffer from the same problems as I do.
Thank you very much.　　　http://qiita.com/kuniatsu/items/203d5d17194b0befb189

Comment: sorry what is this?
Edit:read your edited comment later..great work

Comment: I made Japanese what I taught you.thank you very much.