# Error TS2305: Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member 'Options'. Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using 
fullCalendar & its fullcalendar-scheduler in Angular 5

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { CalendarModule } from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CalendarModule,
```

**home.component.ts**

```
    import { CalendarComponent } from 'ap-angular2-fullcalendar';
    import * as $ from 'jquery';
    import 'fullcalendar';
    import 'fullcalendar-scheduler';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

 calendarOptions: Object = {
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Resource 1' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Resource 2', eventColor: 'green' },
      { id: 'c', title: 'Resource 3', eventColor: 'orange' },
      { id: 'd', title: 'Resource 4', eventColor: 'red' }
    ],
    events: [
      { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-03-07T09:00:00', end: '2018-03-07T10:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
      { id: '2', resourceId: 'b', start: '2018-03-07T07:30:00', end: '2018-03-07T08:30:00', title: 'event 2' },
      { id: '3', resourceId: 'c', start: '2018-03-07T07:30:00', end: '2018-03-07T08:30:00', title: 'event 3' },
      { id: '4', resourceId: 'd', start: '2018-03-07T10:10:00', end: '2018-03-07T10:40:00', title: 'event 4' },
      { id: '5', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-03-07T10:10:00', end: '2018-03-07T10:40:00', title: 'event 5' }
    ]
  };
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ap-angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar.d.ts(3,10):
>   error TS2305: Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member
>   'Options'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(2525,10):
>   error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same
>   type.  Property 'fullCalendar' must be of type 'Calendar', but here
>   has type 'object'.

on

```
ng build
```

[image]

[This solution does not worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899427/fullcalendar-has-no-exported-member-options-getting-error-in-angular)

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "rm -Rf ./node_modules/app-angular2-fullcalendar/node_modules"
  },
```

*any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304008/not-use-an-angular2-fullcalendar

Comment: that is something else.. error is different.

Comment: Have you imported it the same way mentioned in the post?

Comment: @Vikas yes, i did.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue.

**Error:** Full Calendar can not be added in Angular 5 and it shows following errors.

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ap-angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar.d.ts(3,10):
>   error TS2305: Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member
>   'Options'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(2525,10):
>   error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same
>   type. Property 'fullCalendar' must be of type 'Calendar', but here has
>   type 'object'.

**Problem:** There is a different way to use full-calendar scheduler by using Typescript. It is not same as it was in AngularJs

---

**Solution:**

**Step 1**: 
Install following packages

- npm install --save jquery fullcalendar fullcalendar-scheduler
- npm install --save-dev typescript webpack awesome-typescript-loader
  source-map-loader
- npm install --save-dev @types/jquery

**Step 2**:
Add following code in view/html

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**Step 3**:
In component.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';
import 'fullcalendar-scheduler';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'calendar.view.html'
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  containerEl: JQuery = $('#calendar');;

ngOnInit() {

  calendarOptions: Object = {
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    editable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Resource 1' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Resource 2', eventColor: 'green' },
      { id: 'c', title: 'Resource 3', eventColor: 'orange' },
      { id: 'd', title: 'Resource 4', eventColor: 'red' }
    ],
    events: [
      { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-18T09:00:00', end: '2018-04-18T10:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
      { id: '2', resourceId: 'b', start: '2018-04-18T07:30:00', end: '2018-04-18T08:30:00', title: 'event 2' },
      { id: '3', resourceId: 'c', start: '2018-04-18T07:30:00', end: '2018-04-18T08:30:00', title: 'event 3' },
      { id: '4', resourceId: 'd', start: '2018-04-18T10:10:00', end: '2018-04-18T10:40:00', title: 'event 4' },
      { id: '5', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-18T10:10:00', end: '2018-04-18T10:40:00', title: 'event 5' }
    ]                                                                         
  };
}
```

**Most Important**

1. No need to add any module reference in **app.module.ts**

   import { CalendarModule } from "ap-angular2-fullcalendar";
       @NgModule({
         imports: [
           CalendarModule,
2. No need to add any component reference in your component.ts

   import { CalendarComponent } from 'ap-angular2-fullcalendar';